# report viewer is always loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, loading, reportviewer

I have a report, this report created via visual studio 2008
When I call report from browser as url address, work fine.
When I want to use an in Asp.net Page with Visual Studio 2013, top of report is showing but bottom of report always loading.
I'm waiting few times when this state

If I use Internet Explorer:

> JavaScript critical error in (unknown source
>   location)\n\nSCRIPT1001:yetersiz bellek (insufficient  memory english
>   mean)

If I use Chrome:

> VM886:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Too many arguments in function call
>   (only 65535 allowed)

I tried this link but did not happen.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brianhartman/2010/03/21/reports-never-stop-loading-with-vs-2010/

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you seriously have a function with more than 65535 arguments..?

Comment: Hi Rob, This is a big report.

If I call via browser address url normally works and "Loading" word is not any showing. "Report is being generated" writing and report is showing than short time. 

But same report is not showing in asp.net project.